# Django DateField form removing time

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using Django's DateField form in conjunction with a calendar widget to allow users to specify a date range in one of my views.  The calendar widget allows the user to specify times in addition to the dates that they want.  The time shows up in the form when it is posted, but applying `.cleaned_data` removes the time from the value.

My form looks like this:

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_start_date = kwargs.pop('initial_start_date')
    initial_end_date = kwargs.pop('initial_end_date')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required')
    input_formats = kwargs.pop('input_formats')

    super(DateRangeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['start_date'].initial = initial_start_date
    self.fields['start_date'].required = required_val
    self.fields['start_date'].input_formats = input_formats
    self.fields['end_date'].initial = initial_end_date
    self.fields['end_date'].required = required_val
    self.fields['end_date'].input_formats = input_formats

  start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())
  end_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput())
```

The view looks like this:

```
def home(request):
  context_dict = {'boldmessage': "--> To view logs, please turn off any popup blockers <--",'version':"1.0"}

  init_start = convertToDate("2015/2")
  init_end = convertToDate("2015/209")

  if request.method == "POST":
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(request.POST,required=True,initial_start_date=init_start,initial_end_date=init_end,input_formats=dateFormats)
    if daterange_form.is_valid():
        start = daterange_form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        end = daterange_form.cleaned_data['end_date']
    cont_dict = {'start_date':start,'end_date':end}

    return dummy(request,cont_dict)

  else:
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(required=True,initial_start_date=init_start,initial_end_date=init_end,input_formats=dateFormats)
    context_dict.update({'daterange_form':daterange_form})

  return render(request, 'InterfaceApp/home.html', context_dict)
```

The date formats I give the form look like this:

```
django_dateformats = [ "%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S.%f",  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f", "%Y-%z-%H:%M",              "%Y-%z-%H:%M",   \
                    "%H:%M:%S",             "%H:%M:%S.%f",                                                          \
                    "%Y-%m-%d",             "%Y/%m/%d",             "%Y/%z",                    "%Y-%z",            \
                    "%Y-%z %H:%M:%S",       "%Y-%z %H:%M:%S.%f",                                                    \
                    "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f", "%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S.%f", "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S.%f",                         \
                    "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",    "%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S" ,   "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S",        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",\
                    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f", "%m/%d/%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f", "%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S.%f",     "%m/%d/%y",         \
                    "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S",    "%m/%d/%Y",             "%m-%d-%Y",                 "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S",\
                    "%m/%d/%Y_%H:%M:%S" ,   "%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S",    "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"]
```

When I print `daterange_form` (when `request.method=="POST"`) I get this:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_start_date">Start date:</label></th><td><input id="id_start_date" name="start_date" type="text" value="2015/2" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_end_date">End date:</label></th><td><input id="id_end_date" name="end_date" type="text" value="2015-10-17_22:10:00" /></td></tr>
```

In that print out `end_date` has a time associated with it, but no time after `end = daterange_form.cleaned_data['end_date']`

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: You are using a `DateField`, but you also want time, that's not possible. Have you tried `DateTimeField`?

Comment: @ShangWang I didn't realize there was a different form to handle date and time.  I will check it out.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: @ShangWang that fixed it.  Thanks!